# Notation to differentiate between 'which implies' and 'implies'?

Tags: logic, notation

Is there a way to differentiate between 'which implies' and 'implies' in mathematical notation?

I write $\implies$ for both which sometimes feels wrong and lazy to me especially when dealing with logic.

For example:

'$0 = 1$ which implies $0 = 0$' is different from saying '$0 = 1$ implies $0 = 0$'. The former is false (I assert the first statement '$0 = 1$' as well as the implication) while the latter is true.

On paper I would just write for both
$$0 = 1 \implies 0 = 0$$

Comment: The usage you describe could just be replaced with the word "and."  Note that $P\wedge (P\implies Q) \equiv P\wedge (\neg P\vee Q) \equiv (P\wedge \neg P)\vee (P\wedge Q) \equiv P\wedge Q$.  In practice, though, I often see the phrases used interchangeably without the additional implication that the hypothesis must be true, in particular if being used in the middle of a string of implications.

Comment: If you must have a symbol for "which implies" , how about $\therefore$?